# AJAX Request pulling information from arrays with objects in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I need some help getting with an ajax request that I am messing around with. Currently I have this as my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://teamtreehouse.com/garrettsanderson.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(treeHouseDatas) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(treeHouseDatas)
    $.each(treeHouseDatas, function(i, treeHouseData) {
      $('#treehouse-info').append('<p>' + treeHouseData + '</p>');
      console.log(treeHouseData);
    });
  }
});
```

The response I am getting in the console is as follows:

```
Garrett Sanderson

undefined

garrettsanderson

undefined

https://teamtreehouse.com/garrettsanderson

undefined

https://uploads.teamtreehouse.com/production/profile-    photos/194972/avatar_about-me-photo.png

undefined

ed16b4c7fd1211bd25b61bb9efd2d3cf

undefined

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object16: Object17: Object18: Object19: Object20: Object21: Object22: Object23: Object24: Object25: Object26: Object27: Object28: Object29: Object30: Object31: Object32: Object33: Object34: Object35: Object36: Object37: Object38: Object39: Object40: Object41: Object42: Object43: Object44: Object45: Object46: Object47: Object48: Object49: Object50: Object51: Object52: Object53: Object54: Object55: Object56: Object57: Object58: Object59: Object60: Object61: Object62: Object63: Object64: Object65: Object66: Object67: Object68: Object69: Object70: Object71: Object72: Object73: Object74: Object75: Object76: Object77: Object78: Object79: Object80: Object81: Object82: Object83: Objectlength: 84__proto__: Array[0]
```

Newbie

The actual JSON File looks like this

```
    {
name: "Garrett Sanderson",
profile_name: "garrettsanderson",
profile_url: "https://teamtreehouse.com/garrettsanderson",
gravatar_url: "https://uploads.teamtreehouse.com/production/profile-photos/194972/avatar_about-me-photo.png",
gravatar_hash: "ed16b4c7fd1211bd25b61bb9efd2d3cf",
badges: [],
points: {}
}
```

How do I access the badges array and the points object? As of right now I just get the Object, Object spitting out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You dont want a loop, access using treeHouseDatas. badges and treeHouseDatas.points, you have any trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the badges array

You can target the badges array in the each loop and then you get access to the objects inside, now here on you can target the specific keys of the object:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://teamtreehouse.com/garrettsanderson.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(treeHouseDatas) {
    $.each(treeHouseDatas.badges, function(i, tree) {
      $('body').append('<p style="border-bottom:solid 1px #c4c4c4;"><strong>' + 
                         tree.id +':::::</strong>' + 
                         tree.url + '</p>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> and the points object?

```
console.log(treeHouseDatas.points);
```

Comment: Thanks man this worked! I didn't know I could target the badges straight up front.

Comment: @user3159882 every object's key you can access without loop in.

Comment: Gotcha, So I only have to loop if I am entering an array within the object?